# Django APIClient Post Empty

Tags: python, django, testing, view, apiclient

I am writing a test for a post view. It does work, But when I try and post to it with APIClient.post, I get QueryDict: {}. Here is the test:

```
class SMSCreateData(APITestCase):
...
    def test_SMS(self):
        ...
        postData = {'Body': string, 'From': phNum.phone_number}
        self.client.post(reverse('SMS-data'), postData)
```

And here is the view:

```
def SMSSubmitDataPointView(request):
...
    try:
        print request.POST
...
```

Comment: check `request.data` instead of  `request.POST`

Comment: I tried that, I get "'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'".

Comment: No change. I am also pretty sure it shouldn't be JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**urlencode** your post data and set **content_type** to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode  
# In python 2, use this instead: from urllib import urlencode  


response = self.client.post(reverse('SMS-data'), urlencode(postData),
    content_type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
)
```

You will get data in `request.POST`

Comment: I guess you are using client.get method in other places. `request.POST`   Only handles form data. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/

Comment: If you don’t provide a value for content_type, the values in data will be transmitted with a content type of multipart/form-data. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.post